# Can't Cypress tell me what the exact difference is?

Tags: cypress, chai

I am new to Cypress. I am using version 8.3 with the Chai assertions.

When I run a test via the Cypress GUI I get a report (left in the image) and it tells me that my deep equals fails. However it doesn't tell me WHY it fails. It doesn't show me the exact difference. In the console (right in the image) it logs both the actual and the expected object, but then I have to go look myself through all the properties to try and find out where the differences are.

This is the assertions that fails. I compare the actual json response with a saved expected response.

```js
expect(response.body).to.eql(expectedMeting);
```

[image]

Does someone know how I can let Cypress tell me the exact difference here?

Comment: There's an open issue for exactly this: https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/4084

Answer (score 3):

I can't be sure, but it looks like it's the ordering of the properties that causes the failure.

See the Cypress log, the first couple of properties are different. The console output seems to be sorting the properties to help you spot any difference.

You can iterate the properties

```js
Object.keys(expectedMeeting).forEach(key => {
  expect(expectedMeeting[key]).to.deep.eq(response.body[key])
})

// For good measure
expect(Object.keys(expectedMeeting).length).to.eq(Object.keys(response.body).length)
```

This should give you a fail message by key.

---

I'd also take a look at [deep-equal-in-any-order](https://www.chaijs.com/plugins/deep-equal-in-any-order/) if you're concerned about nested ordering. The above will only check top-level keys.

This is a plugin, unlikely to be bundled with Cypress. You'll need this at the top of the test

```js
const deepEqualInAnyOrder = require('deep-equal-in-any-order');
chai.use(deepEqualInAnyOrder)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The problem is not the ordering however but something else which I already found.
But my question was not really about WHY it fails in this instance. My question is how I can get more information from Cypress on why it fails so that I don't have to search for it myself. Maybe this is not possible in Cypress, but I do find that a bit strange.

Comment: Edit: how to get more information without needing to iterate over each individual key

Comment: Why are you opposed to iterating?

Comment: Because it requires more coding. I wish I could just compare two large json objects 'as is' with deep equal. But if it is not possible to do that AND have Cypress tell me which specific properties failed then I will use the iteration.

Answer (score 2):

If you click on the failed assertion, it will print your error to the console.

[image: assertion message]

In the console, you can see all the information relating to the failure.
[image: console information].

(The console is located in DevTools or a similar location depending on your browser.)

Comment: Yes I know this part. The problem is that I am comparing two very large json with lots of deeply nested properties, so if they aren't equal I still have to manually go through each of the properties in the console to find out where the differences are.
I wish Cypress would tell me this directly.

Comment: Cypress uses Mocha's `expect()` API, so this is just following the same behavior that you'd have if running a test with Mocha. If you wanted to see which fields fail, you could iterate through each field, as Fody answered.